# Explain Oracle's Backend process when executing DDL and DML

Tags: oracle

What will happen in the backend when we execute a SQL Statement in an Oracle Database?
There are different process for both DDL and DML. For example DML reads data to the buffer cache and once commit is issued, it will only then update to DB.
Likewise i need to know the entire back end process when a query executed in oracle.
Please explain for both DDL and DML.

Comment: Start with this document: [**Database Concepts** -> Differences Between DML and DDL Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/sqllangu.htm#CNCPT88928)

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask].  There are entire books written on these topics. Not something to be answered in a few sentences on SO.  See @WernfriedDomscheit links.